# PHP Inbox Function

Tags: php, mysql

I received some great help on my last question. Here is where I'm at:

I'm on the very last step of building a threaded messaging system for a dating website project for school and want to highlight a  with a different bg color when a message is new. This is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` 
(
    `id` bigint (20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `fromme` integer (11) NOT NULL, 
    `tome` integer (11) NOT NULL, 
    `subject` varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
    `message` longtext NOT NULL, 
    `mydate` datetime NOT NULL, 
    `thread` varchar (255) NOT NULL, 
    `receipt` varchar (50) NOT NULL, 
    `INDELETE` varchar (5), 
    `SENTDELETE` varchar (5),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

This query determines if there are new messages (works correctly):

```
select * from messages where tome = '$yes' && receipt = 'n' and INDELETE !='y';
```

It then displays for example "3 New Messages."

All this displays correctly. The only problem is the inbox. Ollie Jones and Bill Karwin supplied me with some great help and it does work as intended, however when you return to the inbox after replying, that message is now gone.

```
SELECT messages.id, 
       messages.fromme, 
       messages.subject, 
       messages.message, 
       messages.receipt, 
       messages.mydate, 
       messages.thread, 
       users.firstname, users.lastname, users.image1
  FROM messages, 
       users,
       (SELECT MAX(messages.id) id, messages.thread thread 
          FROM messages
        GROUP BY messages.thread) latest,
 WHERE messages.tome = '$yes' 
   AND messages.INDELETE !='y' 
   AND messages.fromme = users.id
   AND messages.id=latest.id
ORDER BY messages.mydate desc
```

The goal is to keep all of the messages in the inbox, just highlighting the new ones as above and grouping them by thread. Any ideas? Thanks JC

Comment: Isn't this against your school's Honor Policy?

Comment: Why would writing a web app with help violate a school's honor policy?

Comment: @ceejayoz: "... for a dating website project for school..."

Comment: nah the project is "START A BUSINESS"..it's not an actual coding project, it's a biz project.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code that is run when replying to a message. Now compare that to the where clause for the query to pull messages in the inbox.

Something you're doing when a reply is sent is causing the messages not to meet the criteria for the inbox query. Without seeing the reply code, that's the only help I can give.